# Windows XP won't boot after drive transplant

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I moved my hard drive from my Lenovo laptop into my Asus Eee PC netbook. When I started the netbook, after POST all I got was a black screen with a cursor in the upper left corner.

I thought that the migration should work OK because this was a 32-bit version of Windows XP, and the Atom processor in the Asus should support the x86 instruction set. However, I don't know much about Windows, so maybe this was a dumb thought.

I did verify that the BIOS can find the drive.

It required major surgery to replace the drive, so any solution requiring me to remove the transplant drive is not going to fly.

Keeping in mind that the netbook has no optical drive and that I have no other Windows computers (all my other computers run Linux), is there any way I can fix this problem?

Thanks!

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up wiping the drive and installing Linux. At least I know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of: [Swapping hard disk to new PC causes blue screen with Windows Server 2008](https://superuser.com/questions/216259/swapping-hard-disk-to-new-pc-causes-blue-screen-with-windows-server-2008/216260#216260)

Drive "transplants" as you call them are usually not possible in Windows.

Due to the way in which drivers and the windows registry tie themselves to a machine's hardware, simply moving the hard drive from one computer to another usually doesn't give positive results.

Still, from what you are describing, it seems that the only solution you have is the one described in my answer to the question above. You're going to have to either find a USB optical drive and use that to boot the Windows CD or create a bootable USB drive with the Windows installer on it.

Good luck!

Comment: Any hints for creating a bootable USB drive with the Windows installer on it that don't require a Windows box? I trued using unetbootin on Linux, but that apparently only works with Linux isos...

Comment: I used a USB optical drive to do a repair install of Windows XP. I let it reboot, and still have a blinking cursor in the upper left. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It would seem that you aren't having issues with the Windows installation itself, but that the system isn't correctly recognizing your hard drive. Are you sure that you've correctly set the pins on the hard drive to Master and don't have the drive setup in a 'weird' was as a Slave or somethign similar? I'm not sure if these steps are still necessary in modern laptops, but I know that I've had issues with this before on desktop PCs.

Comment: It's a SATA drive; I don't think it even has jumpers. The thing is, I can read the drive just fine in rescue mode or if I boot up using a livecd (I cloned it using Clonezilla, just in case I ended up hosing it by mistake). It seems like the drive physically is fine.

Comment: Then all I can think of is that you've lost your MBR configuration, so the drive doesn't know where to boot from. Windows' recovery console offers tools to fix the MBR, start from there!

Answer (score 1):

It will crash because the motherboard's chipset is different in the other computer.

Windows 9X e.g. 98  You could take the hard drive from one computer to another with a different motherboard chipset.  So, what you did would have worked with Win98

Windows NT (XP,2K,e.t.c.)  cannot. It is built differently.

You're using XP of course..  And you can fix it after the "fail", by doing a windows  xp repair installation.  Boot off the windows XP CD to do so.

You will obviously have to install drivers for your computer's components.. But that's fine. Same as one would have had to do with Win98. (the fact of having to install drivers) and possibly removing old drivers.  You may get by without installing drivers manually.

Note- Some people use a method acronis has to make an image of windows NT(so XP included) from one computer and put it onto another computer with a different motherboard chipset.

Comment: That's funny, I thought that Windows 98 installations couldn't even be moved to another computer with a different *processor* speed.

Comment: @George  i've never heard of that, and if that was the case then you'd need to install windows 98 over itself when upgrading the processor. Or adjusting the speed of the processor(e.g. changing FSB speed). And I don't see why a windows installation would be a function of processor speed, that makes no sense to me either. So for lots of reasons, + i've never heard/read of it, I don't think so George. Where did you hear/read of that?

Comment: @barlop: It was in an old PC repair book, I think... but you're right - it must have been a joke or something because that's the only place I ever heard that.

Comment: @George Edison  Do you remember the name or author of the book you think said it, by any chance?   i doubt it'd have been scott mueller UGRP for example!

Comment: Windows mostly get crashed if we move hard disk on different chipset mothboard. For that we mostly have to install either fresh windows copy or some time we can solve issue by repairing windows or again mother board driver installation.

Comment: The key thing here is the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer); boot with the wrong HAL and chances are you're going nowhere.