# Blinking cursor after repair install on Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have an Asus Eee PC netbook which I [upgraded the drive of](https://superuser.com/questions/225087/windows-xp-wont-boot-after-drive-transplant). After some shenanigans, I was able to do a repair install from my Windows XP CD. However, I still have a blinking cursor in the upper-left-hand corner after POST.

I tried going into the recovery console and doing chkdsk/fixboot/fixmbr with no effect.

**EDIT**: Looks like it won't boot from this drive at all! I went through the destructive upgrade process, and after the Windows setup program rebooted, still no dice. I know the disk itself is working because I can access/modify it through the recovery console and through boot CDs.

What would cause an SSD to not be able to boot, but still be fully accessible? I've tried twiddling the BIOS bits to make it appear as IDE rather than AHCI, but that didn't help.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DD command to zero the hdd from a Linux (ubuntu) live cd, its due to HSM violations, the hdd drive will appear dead until you zero it. If its not that then you may need a new drive. Good Luck